# c++ polymorphism - passing a reference to base class to a function

Tags: c++, polymorphism, base-class

I'm learning about c++ polymorphism. In the code below, a pointer called `shape` of the type of the base class `Shape` is creates and then pointed at the objects `r` and `c`.

The functions `printArea(r);` and `printArea(c);` are then called. However, at the point that these functions are called `shape` is pointing to the address of `c`. So how does it work when you call `printArea(r);`?

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

class Shape {
public:
    virtual float getArea() const = 0;
};

class Rectangle : public Shape {
private:
    float width;
    float height;

public:
    Rectangle(float width, float height) : width(width), height(height) {}
    float getArea() const {return width * height;}

};

class Circle : public Shape {
private:
    float radius;

public:
    Circle(float radius) : radius(radius) {}
    float getArea() const {return 3.14159f * radius *radius;}
};

void printArea(const Shape& shape) {
    std::cout << "Area: " << shape.getArea() << std::endl;
}

int main() {

    Rectangle r(2,6);
    Shape* shape = &r;

    Circle c(6);
    shape = &c;

    printArea(r);
    printArea(c);
    printArea(*shape);

    return 0;

}
```

Comment: How what works? `printArea` expects a reference, what does the unrelated pointer have to do with this?

Comment: It should work fine, both `Rectangle` and `Circle` have an "is-a" relationship to `Shape`. Have you *tried* it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

class Shape {
public:
    virtual float getArea() const = 0;
};

class Rectangle : public Shape {
private:
    float width;
    float height;

public:
    Rectangle(float width, float height) : width(width), height(height) {}
    float getArea() const {return width * height;}

};

class Circle : public Shape {
private:
    float radius;

public:
    Circle(float radius) : radius(radius) {}
    float getArea() const {return 3.14159f * radius *radius;}
};

void printArea(const Shape& shape) {
    std::cout << "Area: " << shape.getArea() << std::endl;
}

int main() {

    Rectangle r(2,6);
    Shape* shape = &r;  // shape stores the address of object r which when further call 
    std::cout<< shape <<endl; //called sends its address
    Circle c(6);
    shape = &c; // same as r is being processed 
    std::cout<<shape<<endl; 
    printArea(r);   // same thing is taking place here reference is passed and then polymorphism come 
    printArea(c);   // into play 
    printArea(*shape);  // as the shape was given reference of c in the end it returns its value

    return 0;

}
```

if u still have any questions feel free to ask in comments!

Comment: "sends it address and so accordingly virtual function works" -- what virtual function?

Comment: @Quentin : ahh! wrote it by mistakenly over there ! fixed it now ! thanks for letting me know ^_^

Answer (score 1):

I would guess your question is *how*, technically, is the call to `getArea` dispatched at run time.

The C++ standard does not prescribe this. It prescribes exactly which implementation must be executed, but not how that is accomplished.

Nearly all extant C++ implementations do that by placing a hidden pointer in each object of class with one or more virtual functions. That hidden pointer points to a table of function pointers, namely pointers to the virtual methods of the class of the object's dynamic type. This is called a **vtable**. And in general the call is dispatched by checking the object's **vtable pointer**, and retrieving the function pointer from the `getArea` item in the vtable, and calling that function.

There are complications for multiple inheritance, but those are just that: complications.

An alternative could be to search up the base class chain for each call.

That would be less efficient but still it's been used, at least in other languages, e.g. in original Smalltalk, and in Borlands GUI class framework for Pascal in Windows in the 1990s.

Another alternative is to place pointers to each virtual function directly in each object, essentially a vtable in each object. That approach is sometimes used in C. The main advantage is that it's conceptually simple. It also avoids one indirection. But it wastes space and doesn't generalize very well.